# How do I manage identities with ETL?

Tags: sql-server, database, etl

I need help figuring out a workflow and I'm not sure how to go about it... Let's say I'm transforming (ETL?) data from Table A to Table B. Table A has a composite primary key A.a+A.b+A.c, while Table B has just an automatically populated identity column. How can I map the composite keys from A back to the identities created when inserting into B?

Preferably I would like to not have any columns in table B related to A's composite key because there are many other tables that need to undergo the same operation but don't have the same composite key structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself exactly what you need the original keys for. The answer may vary depending on the source system. This may lead you to maintain a "source system" column and a "original source keys" column. The latter may need to be a comma-delimited list of the original keys.

Or, you may find that you never actually need to map back, so don't need to keep anything.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you can't relate records from table B back to the records of table A after the transformation unless you somehow capture a mapping between A's composite key and B's identifier during the transformation.

You could add a column to A and pre-compute the identifiers to be used when inserting into B.  Then you would have a mapping.  This could also be done using a separate mapping table, if you don't want to add a column to A.

If you don't want to override the default assignment of identifiers, then you will have to capture them during the load.  Oracle provides the `returning` clause for `insert` in PL/SQL for this purpose.  I'm not sure about SQL Server.  It may also be possible to accomplish this by using a trigger on B to insert into a separate mapping table or update a column in A.  Though that's likely to slow down your load considerably.

If nothing else, you could create additional columns in B to hold the keys of A during the load, query out the mappings into a separate table afterwards, and then drop the extra columns.

I hope that helps.